# Bootstrap 4: I'd like my columns to take the full width of my container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like my **columns** to take the full width of my **container**, I have tried many things but haven't find a *solution how to fix it*.

**Here's an example of what I want:**
[image: wish]

**While it looks like this for now:**
[image: for now]

**See the little red arrows? This is the space that I don't want to see.**

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col ml-auto">
          <div class="card card-body justify-content-center" style="height:150px">

            <h5 class="card-title">Privacy & Security</h5>

            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

          </div>

      </div>

    <div class="col mr-auto">
      <div class="card card-body justify-content-center" style="height:150px">

        <h5 class="card-title">Privacy & Security</h5>

        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

      </div>

  </div>

    </div>

  </section>
```

CSS:

```
.framework {
    background: rgb(27,28,30);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #1b1c1e 0%, #27262d 200%);
    display:grid;
    max-width:100%;
    padding:30px 10px 30px 10px;
    margin-top:0.5em;
    height:100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    .card {
        background: #27262d;
        border-radius:5px;
    }

    img {
        width:50px;
        height:auto;
        display:block;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top:15px;
    }
}
```

CSS (for Mobile version) :

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@800&display=swap');

.framework {
    .card-title {
        font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
        font-weight:800;
        font-size:14pt;
        text-align:left;
        text-transform:uppercase;
    }

    .card-text {
        font-family:geomanist,sans-serif;
        color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.377);
        font-weight:400;
        font-size:10pt;
        letter-spacing:-0.1px;
        line-height:15px;
        text-align:left;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .card-title {
            font-size:11pt;
            }
        .card-text {
            font-size:9pt;
        }
    }

    
}
```

edit (10/19/2020 | 12:09 [brussels])kind of fixed it by adding class ".mx-md-n5" next to class ".row" in the same div, this aint perfect but it satisfies me

Comment: you missed to put the opening section tag in your code

Comment: a simple way you can add bootstrap spacing utilities https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Can really see where you are using framework but you have 10px padding either side. That might be it. `padding:30px 10px 30px 10px;`

Answer (score 0):

### Please add pl-0 and pr-0 class for the remove the padding

```
<div class="col align-self-start pl-0">
      <div class="card card-body justify-content-center" style="height:150px">

        <h5 class="card-title">Privacy & Security</h5>

        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

      </div>

  </div>
```

---

```
<div class="col align-self-end pr-0">
      <div class="card card-body justify-content-center" style="height:150px">

        <h5 class="card-title">Privacy & Security</h5>

        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

      </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div class="col-12 mb-3">
            <div class="card card-body justify-content-center" style="height:150px">

                <h5 class="card-title">Privacy & Security</h5>

                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col ml-auto">
            <div class="card card-body justify-content-center" style="height:150px">

                <h5 class="card-title">Privacy & Security</h5>

                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col mr-auto">
            <div class="card card-body justify-content-center" style="height:150px">

                <h5 class="card-title">Privacy & Security</h5>

                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the predefined Bootstrap classes at first and if you have any custom CSS add it in a new classes.
Is this what you search for:

HTML

```
<div class="container" style="border:1px red dotted">
  <div class="row " style="border:1px blue dotted">
    <div class="col pl-0">
      <div class="card card-body justify-content-center" style="height:150px">
        <h5 class="card-title">Privacy & Security</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col pr-0">
      <div class="card card-body justify-content-center" style="height:150px">
        <h5 class="card-title">Privacy & Security</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a demo for what exactly you want I have just remove padding for the full-width box and for the next two box I remove padding-left for left side box and padding-right for the right side box.

this is the code snippet which helps you to understand what I do.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container p-0">
    <div class="row m-0">
      <div class="col-12 p-0 mb-4">
        <div class="card bg-primary card-body text-center justify-content-center" style="height: 150px; font-size: 50px; color: red;">
          Box 1
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 pl-0">
        <div class="card bg-primary card-body text-center justify-content-center" style="height: 150px; font-size: 50px; color: red;">
          Box 2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 pr-0">
        <div class="card bg-primary card-body text-center justify-content-center" style="height: 150px; font-size: 50px; color: red;">
          Box 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this answer will help you to solve your problem this time and also help you in future for this type of structure.

Thank you...

Comment: please review this answer and update here if you have any doubts